# PostgreSQL. Search for a value through a list of attributes with a specific id

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, search, attributes

I need to make search for an object by specific attributes. I have a table item_attribute:

> #### item_attribute             item_attribute_type_fk            item_fk              value_text
>
> ```
>      1                        1                   1              bbbb
>      2                        2                   1           450-240-310
>      3                        3                   1             800x250
>      4                        4                   1               2,2
>      5                        1                   2               HBO
> ```
>
> etc

I've tried this:

```
SELECT item,name,sale_price,producer,producer_code,store_price,I.type_name 
FROM ((item INNER JOIN unit_type ON unit_type_fk=unit_type) 
INNER JOIN item_store ON item=item_fk)AS I 
INNER JOIN item_attribute AS A ON I.item=A.item_fk 
WHERE store_price BETWEEN 200.0 AND 300.0 
AND (UPPER(value_text) LIKE UPPER('%b%') AND item_attribute_type_fk=1) 
AND (UPPER(value_text) LIKE UPPER('%2%') AND item_attribute_type_fk=4) 
GROUP BY item,I.type_name ORDER BY item
```

Result should be row, where item_fk = 1, but in reality select returns zero rows. If I change `AND` to `OR` between attributes that will result in several rows, which is not exactly what I want, because search need to return only that object, that has **all** attributes, that user typed in in search field. How should I change code, that it will look for a value only through attributes with specific item_attribute_type_fk and return row with object, that has all that attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using an [EAV-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) schema.

To query multiple values in  EAV you have to join the same table multiple times. e.g.

```
SELECT item,name,sale_price,producer,producer_code,store_price,I.type_name 
FROM 
  item 
  INNER JOIN unit_type ON unit_type_fk=unit_type
  INNER JOIN item_store ON item=item_fk)AS I 
  INNER JOIN item_attribute AS a1 ON I.item = a1.item_fk 
  INNER JOIN item_attribute AS a2 ON I.item = a2.item_fk   -- note second join
WHERE store_price BETWEEN 200.0 AND 300.0 
  AND (UPPER(a1.value_text) LIKE UPPER('%b%') AND a1.item_attribute_type_fk=1) 
  AND (UPPER(a2.value_text) LIKE UPPER('%2%') AND a2.item_attribute_type_fk=4) 
GROUP BY item, I.type_name
ORDER BY item
```

Consider transitioning to using `json` or `hstore` for your attributes. It's lots less painful to query.